# How do I make my bot only answer the commands I've coded?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My bot is answering some commands that I didn't code.
Here's my code:

```
else if (!command === 'cctech' || 'tomorrow'){
         client.commands.get('advance01').execute(message, args);
```

I tried putting on this:

```
const command = client.commands.get(command);
if (!command) return message.channel.send("Invalid Command.");
```

But it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line of code:

```js
if (!command === 'cctech' || 'tomorrow')
```

First of all, `!command === 'cctech'` is basically writing whether the opposite of `command` equals `'cctech'`. The correct way to check if two values are not equal is with `!==`.

Second of all, the logical `||` operator will return `true` if one of the two inputs are truthy. A string by itself, such as `tomorrow`, will always be truthy.

```js
if ('random string') console.log("'random string' is truthy");

const str = 'something'
if (str === 'hello' || 'goodbye') 
  console.log('Even though the first expression is falsy, the second input is a stand alone string, which returns `true`')
```

Unfortunately, we can't take shortcuts like that, and we'll have to write out the whole expression twice. Also, you should be using the logical `&&` operator, since *both* inputs should be true in this situation.

```js
if (command !== 'cctech' && !command !== 'tomorrow
```

However, even though your method was not a viable shortcut, there are still a few ways we can make this shorter. The two top ways that come to mind would be with [`Array.prototype.includes`()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and with [`RegEx.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). Here's an example:

```js
const str = 'something';
if (str !== 'hello' && str !== 'goodbye') 
  console.log('This will work');

// if one of the array elements is the command
if (!['hello', 'goodbye'].includes(str))
  console.log('This will work too');

// test a RegEx against the command string
if (!/hello|goodbye/.test(str))
  console.log('This will work as well');
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like a problem in this line of code:

```
if (!command === 'cctech' || 'tomorrow'){
```

try this...

```
 if (!command === 'cctech' && !command === 'tomorrow'){
```

Comment: I changed it to to that, and it all my codes didn't work, the bot doesn't respond to me at all 
 and there is no error messages that appears.